# why the '.pdf' figure produced by gnuplot is large than matlab?

Tags: pdf, size, gnuplot, figure

I used gnuplot to plot a stacked bar figure, the produced .pdf file is 50k. But the figure produced by matlab is 1-9k usually.

When I inserted the gnuplot-produced pdf figure in latex (pdflatex), and open the paper, the figure seems need re-produced (the stacked columns show one by one).

here is the command

----+

set style histogram rowstacked#errorbars gap 1 lw 3#clustered

set style data histograms

set bar

set term postscript eps color "Helvetica" 24

set output "file.eps"

plot

---+

the size of the output 'file.eps' is 26k. the size of 'file.pdf' produced by epstopdf is 65k.

Thank you.

Comment: PDFs are essentially a program written in Postscript. GNUPlot will be writing a different program than Matlab, even though the final output is the same. Just as using `echo "hello world!"` produces a different PHP bytecode sequence than `print("hello world!")`, even though the output is identical.

Comment: pixel density could be different between the two applications, as well.

Comment: Incidently, if you want to include the image in latex - use the epslatex terminal in gnuplot (rather than the pdf): the graph is done in gnuplot but the text is done by latex.  All your founts and sizes will be exactly consistent with the rest of your document (something very hard to do with matlab).

Comment: Also - if you want help with your gnuplot output - it would help if you indicated what commands you use to produce your output.  Your question is more of an observation at present...